# Accessing website using proxy in python

Tags: python, proxy

I am not able to access website. Given below is the code which I used it. I tried to use for application as well for "Multiple Circuit Tor Solution". Hopefully i will get help soon.

```
import urllib2
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':'80.82.69.72:3128'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
url_set_cookie = 'my_website_address'
req = urllib2.Request(url_set_cookie)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14')
opener.open(req)
```

Getting Error

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import urllib2

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '0.0.0.0:9090'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
datum = response.read().decode("UTF-8")
response.close()
print datum
```

Refer [this](http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2008/10/27/python-proxy-client-connections-requiring-authentication-using-urllib2-proxyhandler/)

See, if that helps.

Comment: Getting this <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>

Comment: Are you using proxy ip address? don'nt use 0.0.0.0

Comment: Try using different proxy IP address and port number (even the url).

Comment: I tried this method with different IPs but not able to access it. I am trying to access one of netherlands website.

Comment: Is the error message same, which you where receiving before?

Comment: Not i am getting this error <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>

Comment: Can i use https://proxy-nl.hide.me/index.php  inside my python code to access website. Can you suggest on this part, as i am able to access via this website on browser.